# How to execute this

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols('x,y')
f=complex(x,2*x*y)
Print(f)
```

I need the solution in the form of `x+2xyi`

When I execute above program it is showing "Cannot convert expression to float"

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `complex` function does not work with symbolic variables ([doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy.functions.elementary.complex)).

Below code worked for me:

```py
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
f = x + 2*I*x*y
print(f)
```

Comment: I can't excrete f.real